# insert data to listview by keyboard and view the data

Tags: android

I want to add a list of products with their own cost, but when i add the second product, the values of the second overwrite the values of the first.
What can i do?

Spesa.java

```
public class Spesa  extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spesa_layout);

    final Button add_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);

     final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    final HashMap<String,String> personMap=new HashMap<String, String>();

    final EditText et_main = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_main);
   final EditText costo= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.costo);

    add_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String str = et_main.getText().toString();
            String str2 = costo.getText().toString();
            personMap.put("name", str);
            personMap.put("code", str2);
            data.add(personMap);

            String[] from = {"name", "code"};
            int[] to = {R.id.textView1, R.id.textView3};

    SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data,R.layout.row,from,to);

            //Setting Adapter to ListView

    ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.list)).setAdapter(adapter);

        }});}}
```

How can i delete a product by clicking it?

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(Spesa.this);
            adb.setTitle("Delete?");
            adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + position);
            final int positionToRemove = position;
            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    data.remove(positionToRemove);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// i don't know how to do this 
                }
            });
            adb.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its obvious to happen that because you are using the same instance of HashMap everytime which is going to over-write the previous value with the same key. So, if you don't want to over-write that you have to create another instance of HashMap inside the click event as,

```
add_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

           personMap=new HashMap<String, String>();

            String str = et_main.getText().toString();
            String str2 = costo.getText().toString();
            personMap.put("name", str);
            personMap.put("code", str2);
            data.add(personMap);
            ....
```

Also, you have to remove the `final` declaration for HashMap so that you can use it again inside the `onClick()` event

Comment: ok thanks! And if i want to delete a product by clicking it, how can i do?

Comment: yes, but i have a problem, how can i do notifyDataSetChanged() with the adapter, if the adapter is inside to the onClick?

Comment: Can't you take instance of adapter as global? obviously you can!

Answer (score 0):

your personmap is declared final outside of the onclick event, but does not have any usage there. Put the declaration inside of your onclick event (not final) and you will create a new instance each time that will be added to your data-object. At the moment you are changing the same instance you had before.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem lies in HashMap.
When we pass values with same key in HashMap, it'll override the previous values.

```
personMap=new HashMap<String, String>();

String str = et_main.getText().toString();
            String str2 = costo.getText().toString();
            personMap.put("name", str);
            personMap.put("code", str2);
            data.add(personMap);
```